# TV series about human cops in alien city

Tags: story-identification, gerry-anderson

Saw some of this in early 90's. Two of local police are human (in uniforms), very puppet-heavy (a lot, if not most aliens depicted were puppets rather than actors in costumes) and was advertised as a 'Gerry Anderson Production' (or something along those lines). In one episode the villain was an alien who at first defends citizens in the slum from local crime bosses but later turned out to be a threat to them himself.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Perhaps [Space Precinct](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108938/)? Here is the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Precinct) page for the show.

> The series is set in the year 2040 and starred American actor Ted Shackelford as former NYPD detective Patrick Brogan, now a lieutenant with the Demeter City police force on the planet Altor in the Epsilon Eridani system. Brogan and his partner Jack Haldane (played by Rob Youngblood) must adjust to living in another solar system, and investigating crimes being committed by aliens as well as humans. Also co-starring was Danish actress Simone Bendix as Officer Jane Castle, Haldane's love interest (Brogan being happily married with a wife, daughter and son who made the move to Demeter City with him). All other major characters were played by actors wearing complex make-up that also included elements of puppetry in order to depict the different alien races.

And here is a [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o6EjTBwIJKQ) of the first episode: